# Wordpress > change x-robots-tag

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, seo, lighthouse

I have a Wordpress site that uses the Astra theme. In Chrome's Lighthouse tab it states:

```
Page is blocked from indexing 
Blocking Directive Source 
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow
```

However:

- In Wordpress (Settings > Reading) the box is unchecked for "Search engine visibility: Discourage search engines from indexing this site"
- The source code of the website does nowhere includes text such as "x-robots", "noindex" or "nofollow".

Does anyone understand why the page is blocked from indexing?

---

**Update**:

1. I checked in the network tab, and under response headers it states `x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow`.
2. I looked at the source code of the page to check the meta tags, but there's nothing in there about `x-robots`, `noindex` or `nofollow`.
3. The file robots.txt contains the following:

   User-agent: *

   Disallow: /wp-admin/

   Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

   Sitemap: https://example.com/wp-sitemap.xml

How can I make the Wordpress site not being blocked from indexing?

Comment: Have you checked the headers aren't sending `X-Robots-Tag: noindex`? Just open dev tools on the network tab and look at the actual page request, do you see it set under headers? Also the warning above covers your robots.txt blocking the site so check that and your meta tags blocking robots so check your meta tags. It is a bit confusing as that is a catch all warning for all the ways it could be blocked.

Comment: Thanks, 1) I checked in the network tab, and under response headers it states `x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow`. 2) I added the content of `robots.txt` in my post. 3) I looked at the source code of the page to check the meta tags, but there's nothing in there about `x-robots`, `noindex` or `nofollow`. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Right assuming you have access to your server through FTP I am guessing your `.htaccess` needs adjusting.  Open your `.htaccess` file and look for `Header set X-Robots-Tag...` and delete that line (backup your `.htaccess` first just in case!). If you don't see that then the only other way this could be set is via PHP headers so search all of the site files for `header("X-Robots-Tag:` (you might have missed it if your search was case sensitive).

Comment: I do have FTP access, but what I don't understand is why this situation is happening with a clean Wordpress install? Because it would imply that any freshly installed Wordpress website is automatically not indexed, which I suspect can't be true. I'm sure there are plenty of people with Wordpress, who have never used FTP and therefore wouldn't be able to change this. Is excluding the site from being indexed indeed the Wordpress default... and is there no setting in Wordpress to change this...?

Comment: You could have accidentally caught the "discourage search engines from indexing this site" at install, it is super easy to do. Then whatever theme / plugins you have could have tried to reverse this and gone wrong (if you are using a theme). If you used something like "installatron" to install maybe it is misconfigured to default to no index. It is really hard to say why but my guess is an accidental click in install (which as I said is super easy, especially if you are a keyboard user as it is the one item above the "install wordpress" button.)

Comment: There is a setting in WordPress (which you already found) but if something went wrong with a plugin etc. or the user privileges on the server are not set correctly, it may not work. Fixing the `.htaccess` is easiest (if that is indeed the problem) The important thing is did you find anything and is the issue solved or do you need more help?

Comment: You may also check your nginx Config if you have one. I accidently had `add_header X-Robots-Tag none;` in my server block, and Google interpreted this as "noindex"

Comment: Thanks, good to now it's not by default that it blocks indexing and there's probably some glitch at work. I've checked the `.htaccess` file but there's no line about `robots`. So unfortunately that didn't work. (I can post the htaccess content if you like but wasn't sure if that is safe to do)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to check the nginx config (nor do I know if I have one). I'm hosting on Cloudways / Digital Ocean server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from the hosting agency. The site at the moment is still on a subdomain of the hosting agency. They replied: "It comes from the nginx setup for default domains. Once you will use the domain name this would get resolved." So, once I switch to my own domain it should be resolved and I think the conclusion is that the nginx server configuration is the cause (set up this way on purpose).

Comment: Cheers, had the same with a site on Cloudways.

Comment: Rens, I'm on Cloudways and have my env set to production and getting this issue with X-Robots-Tag being set to noindex, nofollow. When your domain started to resolve did this go away?